# Объединение двух датафреймов по столбцу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, объединение

У меня есть два датафрейма df1 и df2.
Столбцы датафрейма df1:*userid, movieid, rating, timestamp*

Столбцы датафрейма df2:*movieid,tags*

Как объединить эти два датафрейма по столбцу *movieid*?

Ничего, далее `df1.merge(df2)`в голову не приходит, но таким образом все строки столбца *movieid* забиваются одним и тем же значением.[image: Скриншот датафрейма]

Comment: Судя по описанию - df1.merge(df2) должно работать

Comment: Вообще в таких вопросах нужно всегда приводить воспроизводимые примеры входных данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Таким образом все строки столбца *movieid* забиваются одним и тем же значением. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df1["tags"] = df1["movieid"].map(df2.set_index("movieid")["tags"])
```

PS это решение хорошо работает в том случае когда добавить нужно один столбец.